# How to get (console.log) draw calls in interleaved buffer and InstanceMesh threejs

Tags: three.js

I'm a beginner to threejs. As I'm working in performance optimization of instances I'm working on two different samples of InterleavedBuffer and InstanceMesh.

I want to compare the draw call between both Interleavedbuffer and InstanceMesh to find the difference of how optimized it is. How to get the draw call count between them?

Comment: Run your page in Safari. Use the [devtools canvas inspector](https://webkit.org/blog/8452/canvas-debugging/). It will show you all the draw calls. (Yea, sorry if you don't have a Mac)

Comment: You can also try [spector](https://github.com/BabylonJS/Spector.js)

Comment: I don't have a mac  will this works console.log(renderer.info.render) @gman

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`WebGLRenderer` has a property call [info](https://threejs.org/docs/index.html#api/en/renderers/WebGLRenderer.info) which contains a series of statistical information about the graphics card memory and the rendering process. It also reports the amount of draw calls per frame like so:

```
console.log( renderer.info.render.calls );
```

Comment: In my scenario I made 16000 instances of same object and the number of draw calls per frame are 1 but still my browser gets crashes @Mugen87 . ?

Comment: What browser are you using?

Comment: google chrome Version 80.0.3987.149 (Official Build) (64-bit) and some render informations are frame -> 23, calls -> 1, vertices -> 1339728000 , faces -> 44657600 , points -> 0, geometry -> 0 and texture -> 3 @Mugen87

Comment: _vertices -> 1339728000_ O_o more than a billion vertices.

Comment:  Is there any way to overcome it! @prisoner849